# vector problem, get very confused

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ be mutually orthogonal non-zero vectors in $3$-space. So, any vector $v$ can be expressed as $v= c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3$.

Show that the scalars $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ are given by the formula 
$$
c_i=
\frac{\langle v,v_i\rangle}{\|v_i\|^{2}},i=1,2,3
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
Using the equation for $v$, ($v= c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3$), calculate the value of $v\cdot v_i$.

Use distributivity of scalar multiplication and addition, then use the fact that $v_i\cdot v_j=0$ if $j\neq i$